# How to do networking within Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, electron

I would like to build a simple chat app with electron. I wrote a node chat app before using web sockets. Now for a desktop app, I'm wondering how to do networking.

As far as I can see, I have two options: using node's net module, or going through http and actually running a web server as a "chat server".

I guess http has the advantage of being less low-level and more familiar to me, on the other hand I'm wondering if it's not overkill...

Any sugestions?

Comment: In electron app you can use websockets and i would recommend it since it is real-time so more suitable for chat. I'm wondering why you would use net module? I mean in electron you can use same code as in browser, so websockets work out of the box. Well i hope I'm not mistaken, I actually never used electron

Comment: Now, I'm using websocket

Comment: And I found this : https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource